# Is Azure more complicated and slower to deploy than VM/Server architecture?

Tags: azure

I just read [this](http://rlacovara.blogspot.ie/2012/03/should-you-use-net-for-your-statup.html) article from the year 2012 and here is the relevant snippet:

> Microsoft is really pushing Azure as a platform for startups.  I
>   strongly recommend that early stage startups do not use Azure.  Azure
>   development is significantly slower than straight up .Net development
>   that runs on a windows server or VS.  Deployment takes longer,
>   debugging takes longer, the Azure environment is difficult to
>   replicate on your local dev computer, backups are a pain, and you're
>   locked into a single hosting provider.  It all ads up to a lot of
>   inflexibility and friction at a time when your startup needs
>   flexibility and speed over all other things.  Azure can have a place
>   later, when scale is your problem, but at the beginning of your
>   startup that isn't the issue.

I'm working on two new projects for people now and going down the Azure route, mainly as it cuts out the SysAdmin requirement going forward. In my last job I worked on an Azure deployment and found it pretty decent. This was within the last few months.

My question, the above article is from 2012, is it still relevent to now. Am I making a mistake by going with Azure? Thank you.

Comment: Just try it. You get a few hundred dollars of Azure credit for free for first time subscribers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most Azure-related information on the web from 2012 and before is no longer relevant.  In the cloud world, things are often out-dated after two months, let alone two years - things are changing that fast.
Many people using Azure today are doing so for prototyping and PoC's, specifically because it's quicker to deploy an app in Azure than it is to spin up all the required infrastructure in an on-premises environment.  I would definitely go with your own experience over some blog post from 2012.